# How to export a symbol with type "FUNC" and "GLOBAL" in gas assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86, elf, gnu-assembler

The test is on 32bit x86 Linux.

This question is similar with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696633/how-to-export-a-function-in-gas-assembler).

Generally, I defined a function `foo` in my at&t syntax assembly code and I want to
export it as "global function".

I tried this:

```
 .globl foo
 foo:
 ....
```

Then I tried to use check the symbol table with:

```
gcc test.s
readelf -s a.out | grep foo
```

However, the result is:

```
9981: 08061d49     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 config_check_cond
```

The type info shows `NOTYPE` and I want to adjust it into type `FUNC`, can anyone tell me how to adjust it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.type` directive to mark it as a function, such as `.type foo, @function`. You can find further details in the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/as/Type.html).